# Trouble installing Ephem on a custom distribution of Python ie. Maya (3D / CGI software)

Tags: python, macos, installation, maya, pyephem

I downloaded pyEphem for Mac. To install it, I opened a terminal window and went to the folder I unzipped it to, and typed:

```
python setup.py install
```

Works perfectly. However, I use a software called Maya, which I create custom tools for in Python. pyEphem is only useful to me in Maya. How can I install / import ephem in Maya's Python?

Thank you SO much in advance for anyone who can help me with this.
Best,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'd have to use `mayapy` which is Maya's own python version found in `/Applications/Autodesk/mayaVersion/Maya.app/Contents/bin`. So just add that to your `PATH` in your .bash_profile and then you should be able to run `mayapy setup.py install`.
Hope that helps, it's been a while since I've used Mac..

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction! The command I needed to this was:

    sudo /Applications/Autodesk/maya2014/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 setup.py install